# UnimplementedFeatureError: Copying of type struct Test.A memory[] memory to storage not yet supported

Tags: solidity, contract-development

I have this simple contract where I want to save struct `B` with the name "poop" and an empty array of type struct `A` in the list `wow`.

```
contract Test {
    struct A {
        uint balls;
    }
    
    struct B {
        string name;
        A[] As;
    }
    
    B[] public wow;
    
    function create(uint _n) public {
        B memory lol;
        lol.name = "poop";
        wow.push(lol);
    }
}
```

When compiling, I get `UnimplementedFeatureError: Copying of type struct Test.A memory[] memory to storage not yet supported.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems is that `B` memory representation doesn't have the `As` member since it cannot have a storage arrays in memory.

Previous version ignored this and let you assign B, silently ignoring dynamic fields like storage arrays and mappings.

You can workaround by getting a reference to the pushed object and modifying that copy instead.

```
function create(uint _n) public {
    // get a reference to the pushed struct
    B storage lol = wow.push();

    // modify storage instance
    lol.name = "poop";
}
```